# Passar/Receber <Lista> entre páginas e preencher listview C# Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1, xaml

Estou criando uma pequena aplicação para windows phone 8.1, no qual o usuário seleciona quantas checkboxes for necessário, e a partir disso o app percorre num laço todas as checkboxes para verificar quais estão selecionadas, e assim pegar o seu valor, jogando em um  e enviando ao form seguinte, para que seja exibido os itens selecionados em forma de lista, preenchendo um controle listview.

Página 1

```
        List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();
        ClassDados cDados = new ClassDados();

        foreach (CheckBox c in checkboxes)
        {
            if (c.IsChecked == true)
            {                  
                cDados.Pedido = c.Content.ToString();
                lista.Add(cDados);
            }
        }

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Carrinho), (lista));
```

Minha classe

```
class ClassDados
{
    public string Pedido { get; set; }
    public int Valor { get; set; }
```

Página 2

```
public sealed partial class Carrinho : Page
{
    List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();

    public Carrinho()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ClassDados c = e.Parameter as ClassDados;
        Cardapio car = e.Parameter as Cardapio;

    }
```

Meu ponto é: Receber esses dados da página 1 preencher uma listview com os respectivos dados, o que não consigo na verdade, é receber esses dados. (Detalhe: mudei para C# WP a uns meses, e muda algumas coisas de C# winforms para xaml) e por esse motivo não consigo mais trabalhar da forma antiga para receber esses dados. Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está enviando um `List<ClassDados>` para a página 2, então na página 2 você receberá a mesma coisa, por isso, basta mudar o modo com o qual você está recebendo a variável

**Página 1**

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Carrinho), lista);
```

**Página 2**

```
List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Parameter is List<ClassDados>) //checa o tipo do e.Parameter
    {
        lista = e.Parameter as List<ClassDados>; //seta o valor recebido para a variável
    }
}
```

Pronto, agora na variável `lista` você terá as variáveis da página 1. Para enviar os dados para o `ListView`, basta usar um `foreach`.

```
foreach(ClassDados item in lista)
{
     ...
}
```

Se você precisar enviar mais de um objeto para a outra página, utilize um array:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Carrinho), new object[] { lista, lista2, lista3 });
```

Daí na página 2, basta pegar os valores do array

```
object[] objs = e.Parameter as object[];
lista = objs[0];
lista2 = objs[1];
lista3 = objs[2];
```

Espero ter ajudado.